# Slack Desktop app does not log in after browser code entered

Tags: slack

Slack slack-standalone-4.12.0.0.msi

.
When you open the Slack Desktop app, it shows you a green "Login" button.
When you press that button, Slack opens the default web browser and takes you to a Slack sign in page where you enter your email address.
The browser loads a 6-character-code-entering-page.
In your email inbox, you get a code.
You enter the code in the page and press Enter.
.

Then 999/1000, at least in previous versions, the browser somehow wakes up the desktop app and the Slack Desktop App signs in to your Slack workspace.
.

But in this case the desktop app never changes. It remains with the green Login button.

I removed a previous version through appwiz.cpl and installed the latest msi Slack desktop app.(Machine wide version)

I have also tried removing that and installing the latest standard 64 bit installer (not Machine wide).

### How can I fix this?

Bonus Info:

1. Tried enabling "Launch app on login" with details [this link](https://linux4one.com/questions/slack-desktop-wont-open-on-login). The Slack desktop app Preferences don't open at all unless you're logged in I suppose?! Verified on two systems.

[image]

2. I have now verified the latest Slack msi version at least does not open after entering the browser code on 3 separate systems... hmm.